# string formating to a sand clock in C#

Tags: c#, string, recursion

Say I have a string that looks like this:

```
*****
***
*
***
*****
```

I am trying to format it in a way that it will be seen like this:

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

I am using recursion to build this string, this length is 5 but it can recieve any odd number as height, the code is :

```
public static StringBuilder GenerateSandClockWithInput(StringBuilder stringBuilder, uint height)
{
    if (height == 1)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("*");
        return stringBuilder;
    }

    string aestricsLine = NumberToAestrics(height);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(aestricsLine);
    GenerateSandClockWithInput(stringBuilder, height - 2);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(aestricsLine);
    return stringBuilder;
}

public static string NumberToAestrics(uint numberOfAestrics)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAestrics; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("*");
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where are you outputting the spaces before the `*` that you need for your sandclock figure?

Comment: I'm not, my code is showen, I am unsure about the correct way to achive this

Comment: Your `NumberToAsterisks` function need to take the number of asterisks *and* the total length of the line.  Then do the math and figure out how many spaces you need to print before the first asterisk.

Comment: But then it wouldn't work great inside the recursion. Lets say the line length is 5. then when I send 3 I need to somehow remeber that 5 is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try followi

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int height = 5;
            stringBuilder =  GenerateSandClockWithInput(stringBuilder, 0, height);
        }
        public static StringBuilder GenerateSandClockWithInput(StringBuilder stringBuilder, int row, int height)
        {
            if (row == height) return stringBuilder;
            if (row < height / 2)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(new string(' ', row) + new string('*', height - (2 * row)));
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(new string(' ', height - row - 1) + new string('*', (2* row) - height + 2));
            }
            GenerateSandClockWithInput(stringBuilder, row + 1, height);
            return stringBuilder;
        }
```

ng :

Comment: It was very very close :) Please change height - row  in stringBuilder.AppendLine(new string(' ', height - row) to height - row - 1 so I could mark this as correct for future googlers :) Thank you

Comment: I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this and if thats not requirement, you don't have to return that string builder. It's reference type, you'll always have the same one in this code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var clockBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        GenerateSandClock( clockBuilder, 13 );
        Console.Write(clockBuilder.ToString() );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void GenerateSandClock(StringBuilder stringBuilder, uint height, uint indentionLevel = 0)
    {
        var line = NumberToSpaces( indentionLevel ++ ) + NumberToAestrics( height );
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(line);

        if (height == 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        GenerateSandClock(stringBuilder, height - 2, indentionLevel);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
    }

    private static string NumberToSpaces( uint indentionLevel)
    {
        return new string( ' ', (int)indentionLevel);
    }

    private static string NumberToAestrics(uint numberOfAestrics)
    {
        return new string( '*', (int)numberOfAestrics );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the number of white space that should be added before each line and use `new string(char, count)` constructor to add empty string before each line.

You can do it using `String.Split`, `Linq` and `String.Join`. Here is the code.

**Make the original string:**

```
static string Make(int height)
{
    var lines = Enumerable.Range(-height, 2 * height + 1)
                          .Where(i => Math.Abs(i) % 2 == 1)
                          .Select(i => new string('*', Math.Abs(i)));

    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
}
```

**Align Center**

```
static string AlignCenter(string input)
{
    var lines = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    var maxLength = (int)(lines.Max(i => i.Length));

    var result = lines.Select(i => $"{new string(' ', (maxLength - i.Length + 1) / 2) }{i}").ToList();

    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
}
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine(Make(5));

Console.WriteLine(AlignCenter(Make(5)));
```

Comment: This is a step backward from the original code, since it relies on a hard-coded hourglass with 5 rows.  And a LINQ solution is probably less readable than using for loops in this case.